# Inno Setup - Stop windows asking permission to run my application

Tags: inno-setup

I have a 'simple' .exe (`helper.exe`), which is part of a software licensing package. My understanding of this file is that initializes a license file; it is run during install at elevated privileges.

I would like this file to be included with my install.  I created an installer using the Wizard with default settings but every time I try to run my .exe UAC pops up and asks permission.  How can I stop that from happening?

Comment: You will have to modify your [`application's manifest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374191%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to not set the `requestedExecutionLevel` node to `level="requireAdministrator`. It has nothing to do with the setup itself.

Comment: Hi there - thank you for your comment.  I had continued searching and just started reading about the manifest... the file is provided by a third party... it seems strange, given the nature of the product, that they would distribute a file for license check that requires elevated privileges....

Comment: The other way which is not the best is to set compatibility flag `RUNASADMIN` for the application in the registry. Example: `Root: "HKLM"; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers\"; ValueType: String; ValueName: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; ValueData: "RUNASADMIN"; Flags: uninsdeletekeyifempty uninsdeletevalue; Check: not IsWin64; MinVersion: 0,6.0; OnlyBelowVersion: 0,6.1.9600` But as I've said this is not the best way especially when you are the developer of the application which needs admin rights (what means you are able to program it to set own privilages)

Answer (score 1):

The first part of the answer was given by TLama:

> You will have to modify your application's manifest to not set the
>   requestedExecutionLevel node to level="requireAdministrator. It has
>   nothing to do with the setup itself.

Later I realised I was using the file incorrectly...

I have edited the question so remainder of the answer is: helper.exe is used to initialize a license file and is supposed to be run once (I thought helper was used to check the license file and thus was supposed to be run for each check).  For the record the software seems really good (I'm currently evaluating).

Cheers,